# Regular expression to remove a substring between two strings

Tags: java, regex

There are similar examples around, but I am not able to find my solution

Objective: Remove all (including) the data between /* and */. I am using below code

```
String str="this /* asdasda */ is test";
str = str.replaceAll("/\\*.*?\\*/","") ;
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
this  is test
```

Problem comes when these are nested

```
String str="this /* asdas/* extra comments */da */ is test";
str = str.replaceAll("/\\*.*?\\*/","") ;
System.out.println(str);
```

Output

```
this da */ is test
```

I am not able to solve the nested part. I need it to discard anything between /* and */

For example

```
"this /* asdas/* extra commen/*   asdas  */  ts */da */ is test /* asdas */ asdasd ";
```

should transalate as

```
this  is test  asdasd
```

Comment: In the nested case what is the expected output ?

Comment: @OfirG: same. Modified the Q

Comment: the characters you dilling with are only eng letters and '*'  '/'  ?, or you can't know for sure ?

Comment: Only eng letters and /* and */

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java doesn't support recursive matching so you won't be able to get it done all in one go. For languages that do support recursive regex matching, you can try something like:

`(\/\*(?>[^\/\*\*\/]+|(?1))*\*\/)`

To emulate recursive matching in Java you can add logic outside the actual regex (do several passes).

Taking out the `|(?1)` `or` part, you have

`(\/\*(?>[^\/\*\*\/]+)*\*\/)`

If you use a pattern matcher like so:

```
    String regex = "(\\/\\*(?>[^\\/\\*\\*\\/]+)*\\*\\/)";
    String str="this /* asdas/* extra commen/*   asdas  */  ts */da */ is test /* asdas */ asdasd ";;

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
    while (m.find()) {
        str = m.replaceFirst("");
        m = p.matcher(str);
        System.out.println(str);
    }

    // here your string is 
    // this  is test  asdasd
```

The last pass will give you the string you're looking for

See https://regex101.com/ to try out regexes online, I find it helpful.

Answer (score 2):

change the regex in `replaceAll` to `/\\*.*\\*/`

running :

```
String str="this /* asdas/* extra comments */da */ is test";
str = str.replaceAll("/\\*.*\\*/","") ;
System.out.println(str);
```

output:

```
this  is test
```

running :

```
String str="hello /*/* asdas/* eer/* hemmllo*/ */da */ */world";
str = str.replaceAll("/\\*.*\\*/","") ;
System.out.println(str);
```

output:

```
hello world
```

### **EDIT :**

assuming you work with simple words, try this :

```
replaceAll("(/\\*( *(\\w) *)*)|(( *(\\w) *)*\\*/)","").replaceAll("\\*/|/\\*","");
```

*test 1 :*

```
String str="/* huhu /* jij */ /* */ here /* asfas /* kjk */ kh*/ here to";
str = str.replaceAll("(/\\*( *(\\w) *)*)|(( *(\\w) *)*\\*/)","").replaceAll("\\*/|/\\*","");
System.out.println(str);
```

output :

```
   here  here to
```

*test 2:*

```
String str1="this /* asdas/* extra commen/*   asdas  */  ts */da */ is test /* asdas */ asdasd ";
str1 = str1.replaceAll("(/\\*( *(\\w) *)*)|(( *(\\w) *)*\\*/)","").replaceAll("\\*/|/\\*","") ;
System.out.println(str1);
```

output:

```
this  is test  asdasd
```

*test 3:*

```
String str2="this /* /* i */ is /**/ */ test";
str2 = str2.replaceAll("(/\\*( *(\\w) *)*)|(( *(\\w) *)*\\*/)","").replaceAll("\\*/|/\\*","") ;
System.out.println(str2);
```

output:

```
this   is   test
```

Comment: Posted in question itself becuase not able to format comments

Comment: Thanks for helping me on this. After removing all characters between /* and */
1. Test1
/* huhu   here  here to
2. Test2
this  is test asdasd 
3. Test3
this  test

Comment: I think regex wont help me and i will have to write separte logic for this to iterate thru string